# Index Usage using Dynamic Management View MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check the index usage of a MSSQL Database using Dynamic Managament View for 3 tables for which I have created a view.

Can someone explaine me how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may get you started.

```
select * 
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
join sys.indexes i  on s.object_id = i.object_id
join sys.index_columns ic on i.object_id = ic.object_id
join sys.tables t on ic.object_id = t.object_id
```

There's a lot of information but just select the columns you need.